# Make text input fill available space between two other elements in one row

Tags: html, css

I have a 'row' div that contains, essentially, a label, then a text input, then a hyperlink. My problem here is I wish the width of the input to always fill the available width between the label and the hyperlink. I have tried numerous approaches, but with only varied forms of failure. I suspect maybe I can use some sort of margin voodoo to make the `a` tag not `absolute`, and always have the `input` neatly bounded by the `lable` and the `a`, but I am now at a complete loss as to what to try next.

Here is my HTML:

```
<fieldset id="ctl00_cph_previousContacts" class="previousContactsArea">
  <legend>Previous Contacts</legend>
  <div class="email-row">
    <label for="ctl00_cph_addressTo">To</label>
    <input name="ctl00$cph$addressTo" type="text" id="ctl00_cph_addressTo" class="email-address text" />
    <a href="#" id="ctl00_cph_addToAddressTo">Add...</a>
    <span id="ctl00_cph_addressToValidator" dynamic="True" style="display:none;"></span>
  </div>      
</fieldset>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.manualNotification #recipientsTab .email-row {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.manualNotification #recipientsTab .email-row label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.manualNotification #recipientsTab .email-row a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```css
.email-row {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
.email-row label {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.email-row input {
  flex: 1;
}
.email-row a {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="ctl00_cph_previousContacts" class="previousContactsArea">
  <legend>Previous Contacts</legend>
  <div class="email-row">
    <label for="ctl00_cph_addressTo">To</label>
    <input name="ctl00$cph$addressTo" type="text" id="ctl00_cph_addressTo" class="email-address text" />
    <a href="#" id="ctl00_cph_addToAddressTo">Add...</a>
    <span id="ctl00_cph_addressToValidator" dynamic="True" style="display:none;"></span>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/97rbu2wy/1/)

Comment: I have to be IE 8 compliant :-(

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in your question to avoid answers that would be of no use to you.

Comment: I no longer have to be IE8 compliant. Yay, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please add flowing css end of your css:

div.email-row{max-width: 30%; float:left;margin-right:20px}

see the following links for more details: 
http://www.cssdesk.com/gDzpd